# Ask the path to user export txt files c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that allows the user to export data to txt, however I want first to ask user what is the path to create the txt. However I'm not getting right the replace function, I doing adding a variable. 
Sorry if it's a sily question.

What I have tried:

```
string path = @"##Insert##\export.txt";

Console.WriteLine("Insert the path to export txt: ");
string temp = Console.ReadLine();
path = path.Replace($"##Insert##", "{temp}");
```

Answer (score 2):

do not do that , use the Path class the manipulate file paths.

assume you get directory in dir.(via prompt, config,...)

```
var dir = <path here>;
var fullPath = Path.Combine(dir, "export.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last line of code at `path = path.Replace($"##Insert##", "{temp}");` with `path = path.Replace($"##Insert##", temp);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use the `Replace` method but use [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead

```
string path = @"{0}\export.txt";

Console.WriteLine("Insert the path to export txt: ");
string temp = Console.ReadLine();
path = String.Format(path, temp);
```

But that's only a workaround that will work in your particular case, you would rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)